# is this an emberjs bug, as a totally empty jsfiddle throws handlebars error

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Is this a bug in emberjs. this totally empty fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5md8/1/ returns  "Ember Handlebars requires Handlebars 1.0.beta.5 or greater" but under manage resource it has the latest handlebars 1.0.beta.6 and latest emberjs. In terms of their order, handlebars.js is first and then emberjs is under it.

**Update**

Emberjs is being loaded now - http://imgur.com/TKb7F and the error of requires Handlebars is still happening https://i.stack.imgur.com/LonQD.jpg

Comment: I don't see an error in the console for that fiddler, looks like it is working to me.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I have added screenshots to show that even when emberjs is loaded, it still throws up the error at my end, so strange.

Comment: Hmmm.  I have the same ember build number in my source (removed all history ever); I tried it in Chrome, Safari & FF on my Mac; through a VM, and on my phone (I [forked](http://jsfiddle.net/scispear/wwyGS/) it so I could test on the phone).  I wish I could reproduce it but not sure I can help.

Comment: @SciSpear, many thanks. You have already helped by making me know it is not an emberjs bug, since it was working at your end. This led to my inspection and elimination steps that led to the removal of a breakpoint which was auto set by chrome developer tool for a different exception in a different jsfiddle earlier on and voila everything worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head banging, i found that an earlier exception resulted in a breakpoint that was auto set by the chrome developer tool. Once i removed the breakpoint, it worked as expected.